# Display welcome message to first-time visitors

Tags: php, javascript, html

Looking for a simple way to show a welcome message to first time visitors on my website.
What's the best approach?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using a cookie:

```
if (empty($_COOKIE['first_time'])) {
    show_welcome_message();
    setcookie("first_time", 1, time()+157680000);  /* expire in 5 years */
}
```

Of course, if the users clears his cookies, he'll see the message again. If he doesn't accept cookies, he'll see the message all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Without an authenticated session (login), you're forced to using a cookie. If the cookie isn't present, set it and simultaneously display the welcome message.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie. If the visitor doesn't have the cookie for your site, then display a welcome message. This isn't a foolproof method (it is trivial for a user to delete cookies), however it's the best you can do.