# Popup modal by "Browser Session"

Tags: javascript, html

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

      $('#exampleModal').modal('show');

  });
```

Above code is my popup modal , but what i wanted is :

Popup Based on browsers ( which means that if user first time surf the site , it will show the modal , but after user close browser and reopen the site with same browser , the pop up modal will show - if user did not close the browser * just the site and he re-open the site there will be no pop up modal "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use session storage:

> "The sessionStorage property accesses a session Storage object for the
>   current origin. sessionStorage is similar to localStorage; the
>   difference is that while data in localStorage doesn't expire, data in
>   sessionStorage is cleared when the page session ends.
>   [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)
>   "

On the above link you will see examples.

Here is how you can implant it with your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  if(!sessionStorage.getItem('firstVisit')) {    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');  }    // show modal if it first time
  $('.close')[0].click(function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('firstVisit',true); // used to store the state across refreshes.
  });
});
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Year Sales</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <a href="/promotion.php"><img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/promotion-vector-stamp-isolated-white-37908603.jpg" style="height:800px; width:800px;"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This snippet won't work here on stack due to: 'SecurityError: The operation is insecure' - so just copy-paste it.**

Enjoy code!

Comment: @greenboxgoolu check this please.

Comment: implement the code on the site , still showing after closing the popup

Comment: even when you push the close button?

Comment: after some modify with your codes work now . thanks

Comment: Glad i could help! (:

Answer (score 2):

You can use "sessionStorage" in javascript. It definitely helps you to detect browser closing event.

See this link:

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/html5-web-storage.php

Comment: Saw that tutorial , what if that there is no "close" button , as user able to "click" on the image for redirect or click outside of the popup modal to close the popup

Answer (score -1):

You can use cookies for this

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Implementation)

> If the cookie setter does not specify a date, the cookie is removed once the user quits his or her browser.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3079934/12680999) you can use it for your approach like:

```
if (empty($_COOKIE['first_time'])) {
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for the help , but wanted to ask , where do i set the "cookies" ?  
and will cookie be deleted if i close the browser ?

Comment: Yes the cookies will be deleted if your browser is closed, at least according to Wiki.

Comment: Thanks, saw it , but where do i set the cookies at ? for "first_time"

Comment: I'm assuming you are using js. You can set cookie via `document.cookie = "first_time=first_time";`

Comment: You can learn more about javascript cookies in here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp